# How to convert date column value which is in CST timezone

Tags: sql, date, hive, timestamp, hiveql

For example column name `Start_date` is having value like below in hive which datatype is `string`

> 02-JUN-22 11.13.22 AM CST

I want to convert the value as below

> 2022-06-02

tried `to_Date` function but getting `null` values

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `to_char` on your query?

for example:

```
select to_char(start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') from your table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below one,

And also if you have 'AM CST' values included as part of your input string, then you can trim or take substring value to match the below query.

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('02-JUN-22 11.13.22' ,'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [DateTime/TimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) functionality

```
<?php
$mysqlDate = '2009-04-01 15:36:13';
$dateTime = new DateTime ($mysqlDate);
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to timestamp in Hive format taking into account the timezone (use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col, pattern))`), see [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), then use to_date.

Demo:

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('02-JUN-22 11.13.22 AM CST','dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a z')))
```

Result:

```
2022-06-02
```